# Original-poster's-name-background overlaps blue selection

Tags: bug, design, comments

On Ask Ubuntu, when you select a multiline comment that the OP posted, the background on the name is below selected text:

[image]

[image]

There is a small gap there (2px).

On the workplace it is different:

[image]

[image]

Overlap! That's 9px there.

Removing the padding doesn't help 100% though:

[image]

Still 2px overlap there...

Adjusting the margins also doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Multi line comment so you can see this happening: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco

Comment: There is no question here. Do you think this is a problem?

Comment: @Bernhard I did add the [meta-tag:bug] tag - I think that this is a problem as it doesn't fit with other site's designs - for no practical reason.